# Single JSON Object read Title render method issue in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have following code which render an console single Object json. When I try to render title or content it gives me an error.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    
    export default class Single extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
                super(props)
            
                this.state = {
                    postData :[]
                     
                }
            }
        
            componentDidMount() {
                axios.get(`https://example.co/wp-json/wp/v2/company/2575`)
                  .then(res => {
                    const postData = res.data;
                    this.setState({ postData });
                  })
              }
        render() {
    
            return (
                
                <div>
                    {/* {console.log(this.state.postData)} */}
                <section className="sf-detail-page">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-10 detail main">
                  <div className="row detail-page-compnay-content">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                       {console.log(this.state.postData)}
                 <h1 key={this.state.postData.id}>{this.state.postData.id}</h1>
                 <h2 key={this.state.postData.id}>{this.state.postData.title.rendered}</h2>
```

)
            }
        }

> {"id":2575,"date":"2020-08-22T04:53:04","date_gmt":"2020-08-22T04:53:04","title":{"rendered":"Vasim"},"content":{"rendered":"This is demo"}}

[image]

**Update Code :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Single extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        
            this.state = {
                postData :Object
                 
            }
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get(`https://example.co/wp-json/wp/v2/company/2575`)
              .then(res => {
                const postData = res.data;
                this.setState({ postData });
              })
          }
          
    render() {

        if (!this.state.postData) {
            return(
                <div>Loading...</div>
            )
        }


        return (
            
            
            <div>
                {/* {console.log(this.state.postData)} */}
            <section className="sf-detail-page">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-10 detail main">
              <div className="row detail-page-compnay-content">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                   {console.log(this.state.postData)}
             <h1 key={this.state.postData.id}>{this.state.postData.id}</h1>
             <h2 key={this.state.postData.id}>{this.state.postData.title.rendered}</h2>
             
          
            

                </div></div></div></div></div></section>
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error ? the warning in your console ?

Comment: You expect yo receive an array from response postData :[] I guess, but you address to it like to an Object. Or, if it's really an Object, then this.state.postData.title doesn't exist while first render. You have to ask if it's exist

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.postData` is an empty array on first render and you're trying to access `this.state.postData.title.rendered`, which will not work.

1. Change initial state to `null` instead of `[]`
2. Add a condition before rendering the data to check if it's loaded yet. Something like:
   `if(!this.state.postData) return "loading..."`